# ToString object content differs from content in debug view

Tags: java, json, hibernate, debugging, orm

ToString object content differs from content in debug view **and** differs from JSON format.
CategoryRelations table content

```
categoryId | parentId
17         | 1
```

Category table content

```
categoryId 
1
17
```

Here is my Java code for select with parents

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Category.class).add(
Restrictions.eq("parent", new Category(parentId))).list();
```

Result of toString in debug mode

```
Category{id=17, parent=Category{id=1, parent=null}}
```

Json result and result for debug view (but there it represented in other format)

```
[{"id":17,"name":"Seventeenth category","image":"17.png","parent":{"id":0},"children":[]}]
```

Category Java code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements NamedModel{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")})
    private Category parent;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Category> children;//...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", parent=" + parent +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {//...
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parentId/{id}", method = GET)
    public List<Category> getByParentId(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {
        return categoryDAO.getByParentId(id);
    }
}
```

**Spring**

```
4.2.6.RELEASE
```

**GSON**

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

CategoryRelations Java code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS")
@IdClass(CategoryRelations.CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
public class CategoryRelations implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID")
    private long categoryId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID")
    private long parentId;

    @Entity
    @IdClass(CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
    public static class CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey implements Serializable    {
        private long categoryId;
        private long parentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the toString-Method in your Entity.

Comment: Seems the problem resides in the code  you use for converting this result into JSON. Can you post that code ?

Comment: Thank you very much, Seth and Thanga!

Comment: @Seth, I've attached toString method to the post.

Comment: @Thanga, I am using RequestBody without additional settings, controller code attached too.